# Converting `webm` to `mov` format using ffmpeg loses transparency - how can I keep it?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm, ffprobe

I am trying to convert a `webm` video to `mov` format without losing quality and transparency using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i input.webm ouput.mov
```

The video gets converted, but it loses transparency and the background of video is black.

I also tried [the following command](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/cyp5vh/comment/eyteeig/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

```
ffmpeg -c:v png -i input.webm output.mov
```

But it gives me the following error output:

```
  libavutil      58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavcodec     60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavformat    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  4.100 /  9.  4.100
  libswscale      7.  2.100 /  7.  2.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
[png @ 0000028041ca7000] Invalid PNG signature 0x824983420031F031.
[matroska,webm @ 0000028041c91240] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: png, none(pc, progressive), 800x800): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'hero.webm':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: qt
    creation_time   : 2023-02-23T10:43:46.703800Z
    MAJOR_BRAND     : qt
    MINOR_VERSION   : 537199360
    ENCODER         : Lavf59.35.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1378 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: png, none(pc, progressive), 800x800, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
      ENCODER         : Lavc59.56.100 libvpx-vp9
      DURATION        : 00:00:09.000000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[png @ 0000028041ca7680] Invalid PNG signature 0x824983420031F031.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

How can I maintain transparency when converting from `webm` to `mov` format?

Here's the video info in case it can be helpful:

```json
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "vp9",
            "codec_long_name": "Google VP9",
            "profile": "Profile 0",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 800,
            "height": 800,
            "coded_width": 800,
            "coded_height": 800,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "film_grain": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": -99,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "field_order": "progressive",
            "refs": 1,
            "r_frame_rate": "24/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "24/1",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "alpha_mode": "1",
                "ENCODER": "Lavc59.56.100 libvpx-vp9",
                "DURATION": "00:00:09.000000000"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": ".\\hero.webm",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "matroska,webm",
        "format_long_name": "Matroska / WebM",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "9.000000",
        "size": "1550466",
        "bit_rate": "1378192",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "COMPATIBLE_BRANDS": "qt  ",
            "creation_time": "2023-02-23T10:43:46.703800Z",
            "MAJOR_BRAND": "qt  ",
            "MINOR_VERSION": "537199360",
            "ENCODER": "Lavf59.35.100"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://www.quora.com/Do-MOV-files-support-transparency) lists a few encoders supported by MOV container that support transparency: Apple Animation, Apple ProRes 4:4:4:4, and Avid Meridien.

Comment: yes, add encoder and pix_fmt: `ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i input.webm -c:v prores -pix_fmt yuva444p10le ouput.mov`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов This worked! Thank you so much! Can you post that as an answer so that I mark it as an "answer"?
Also thanks @zett42! You made me realize what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Meanwhile, my `webm` format was about ~2mb, but after it got converted it turned out to be around ~68mb. I guess `webm` is compressed by default. I wish that I could get the `mov` format with the same size-ish.